# Is it possible to create Outlook Report (and how, if yes)

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am looking for a way to create an outlook report that would contain following  info:
- date and time of message appearance in Inbox 
- date and time of marking message as "Read"
- date and time of categorizing message as "Yellow".

Is it possible with standard Outlook? If not, are there any extensions or add-ons that allow users to do such reports?

Big thank you for help!

Comment: Hi, have you checked this url? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations

Answer (score 0):

According to you deacribe, you could create a Outlook macro rules.

Use vba code to implement the features you want.

You could create macro rules with the below link:

[How to automatically download/save attachments from Outlook to a certain folder?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3747-outlook-auto-download-save-attachments-to-folder.html)

You could change the vba code to the vba code you need.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to monitor the Items collection for each folder containing the emails whose property changes you want to monitor.  All of the info you are looking for is available on the MailItem object (e.g. Categories, UnRead and ReceivedTime). See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemchange

The output and format of the report is up to you - there's nothing specific in the Outlook Object Model to help you create that.